# serving shopify app inside admin.shopify.com always opens new tab with old my-store.myshopify.com url

Tags: reactjs, typescript, popup, shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

Whenever I run `shopify app serve` and open the ngrok URL in the browser, it correctly loads inside `admin.shopify.com` but then immediately opens the old `my-store.myshopify.com` URL in a new tab.

The app then loads correctly in both tabs.

A screen recording can be found here: https://www.veed.io/view/e0283bc6-a3b5-4afb-8044-1839e43e1e9b

This behavior is super annoying and I am getting nowhere with debugging.

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about debugging this?
I am pretty sure that none of my own code opens a new tab and suspect it is AppBridge or another Shopify library.